# How to specify a python version on databricks?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, databricks, gcp-databricks

I am using `GCP` to run `Databricks` and using `pip` to install `guidedlda`. It seems like `guidedlda` uses atleast python version 3.7.

How can I mention the python version in databricks configured for GCP?. I can see an option on `Azure` and `AWS` but not on `GCP`. Here is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Python is included in Runtime.
Below table is including runtimes and python version:

| Runtime | Python |
| --- | --- |
| 10.1 | 3.8.10 |
| 10.0 | 3.8.10 |
| 9.1 LTS | 3.8.8 |
| 9.0 | 3.8.10 |
| 8.4 | 3.8.8 |
| 8.3 | 3.8.8 |
| 7.3 LTS | 3.7.5 |

For example you can check that for 9.0 is Python 3.8.1 here
https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/9.0.html I am including example screenshot with python version.

Here is the list of all releases https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/releases.html

[image]